# FeedMe certificate verification issues

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm working on an import of a feed from a Simple Machines Forum (SMF) which contains images from lots of external sources. Some of the images are importing OK, but most of them are failing with:

> fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.

I haven't been through all of the ones that have failed, but each one I've looked at, I can open directly in a browser tab. Most of them are `https` addresses. Some are `http` addresses that redirect to `https` versions.

Most of the ones that are failing are from `i.imgur.com` or the client's own domain (although I'm doing the import on my local copy of the site at the moment).

Has anyone else ever come across similar errors and how did you resolve them?

EDIT: Just discovered that the client's domain is being protected by Cloudflare.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a bad/out-of-date/misconfigured local certificate on whatever sever you're triggering the import on. Not really Craft related, but tons of potential things to look through to fix/workaround: https://www.google.com/search?q=%2B%22tls_process_server_certificate%3Acertificate%22

Comment: So the problem is with the server that Craft is on, that we're importing into, not the remote server that we're getting the images from?

Comment: That would be my guess based on the error...